# Select an id in php script from a DB (Android)

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm developing an app for android that uses a DB on a server.
I wrote some script php to create new rows in some tables and get all elements from a table (using JSON to exchange data between android and mysql).
Now I have a problem:
i need to select an id from a table and then use this to insert a row in anothere table that has this foreign key.
Well, when I try to select my id, i don't know why, but look like it doesn't work.

Here a simple example how I select this `id`:

```
//connect to DB...
$result = mysql_query (*SELECT id FROM 'table' WHERE name = $name );

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$id = $row['id'];
```

When i use this to select an id, and put it in another query (always on the same connectio) nothing is stored.
if I force the value manually, and so in the same second query I put a number of a preesisting id, the insert works, so the problem is in this piece of code.

Hope someone could help me.

Thank you!

Comment: so what does this $id return to you , a valid id or it not valid?

Comment: Sure, this is the id of a row yet inserted in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you have put on the question, contains syntax errors.
- Remove * from the start of query
- put the query inside " "
- remove single quote ('table') from table name

Here is the modified code:

```
//connect to DB...

$result = mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = $name" );

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$id = $row['id'];
```

Also you should escape the parameter `$name` in query. And you should use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql extension.

Comment: Thank you sir, i will try later modifying these things.

Comment: The problem is that i dididn't copy the real code, i m not at home.. the query wasnt a problem, because i checked it on phpmyadmin (cchangin the variable in php) and it worked. For you the extraction of id is right? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. My doubt was about if the mysql_fetch_assoc fetchs well my data in an int.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$result = mysql_query (*SELECT id FROM 'table' WHERE name = $name );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
while($row > 0){
$id = $row['id'];
}
```